# How do I jump from a diff hunk to the relevant commit(s)?

Tags: magit

I am reading a diff between two revisions, say `A..B`, possibly limited to a single file.

Once in a while, I stumble on a hunk that I’d like to investigate in detail. I want to press a key or two and see the commit(s) that introduce the change I’m currently looking at.

Since that is kind of vague, let’s say I want the equivalent of <kbd>l =L</kbd> `file` <kbd>RET</kbd> `start,+lines` <kbd>RET l</kbd> `range` <kbd>RET</kbd>, where `file`, `start` and `lines` are taken from the current hunk and `range` is the current diff’s range. The log should not be limited to the file, even if the diff was.

I can do this manually but I want to automate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not supported. There already exist requests for similar features and I plan to implement such things eventually. So it's not strictly necessary that you open a feature request for this, but if you want to really make sure I don't forget about this particular variant, then you might want to open one anyway.

Comment: I opened [#2811](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2811).

Answer (score 0):

As a stopgap, I’m going to try this:

```
(defun yk-magit-log-hunk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((yk-diff-range (car magit-refresh-args)))
    (magit-section-case
      ('hunk (let* ((yk-file (magit-section-value (magit-section-parent it)))
                    (yk-hunk-lines (nth 2 (magit-section-value it)))
                    (yk-line-range (replace-regexp-in-string
                                    "^\\+\\([0-9]+\\),\\([0-9]+\\)$"
                                    "\\1,+\\2"
                                    yk-hunk-lines)))
               (magit-log (list yk-diff-range)
                          (list (concat "-L" yk-line-range ":" yk-file))
                          nil)))
      ('file (let ((yk-file (magit-section-value it)))
               (magit-log (list yk-diff-range) nil (list yk-file)))))))
```